# How to scrape HTML elements with no class or id specified in attribute with Beautifulsoup4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape separate content description from a page, i can do it with **class** or **id** specified in **attribute**. But.. i don't know how to get the element if in the html **tag** doesn't specified a **class** or **id** attribute.

Like this screenshot:

[image]

```
<div class="cat_box_desc">
    <h3>Status:</h3>
    on-going <br>
    <h3>Genres:</h3>

    <br>
    <h3>Description:</h3>
    <div align="justify">
        <p> Information</p>
        <p>Type: TV</p>
        <p>Episodes: Unknown</p>
        <p>Status: Currently Airing</p>
        <p>Aired: Oct 7, 2013 to ?</p>
        <p>Producers: Sunrise, TV Tokyo, Sotsu Agency</p>
        <p>Genres: Mecha</p>
        <p>Duration: 25 min. per episode</p>
        <p>Synopsis:</p>
        <p>Gundam Build Fighter adalah sebuah pertarungan simulasi Gundam. Unit Gundam dirangkai dari model plastiknya. Tokoh utamanya adalah seorang anak laki-laki yang bernama Iori Sei. Sei memiliki kemampuan merangkai Gundam yang hebat, namun dia tak
            memiliki kemampuan untuk mengendalikan gundam yang ia rangkai saat melakukan Gunpla Battle. Namun satu hari dia bertemu dengan seorang pencuri roti misterius, yang memberinya sebuah batu permata.</p>
    </div><br>
    <div style="padding-left: 560px; padding-bottom:20px;" class="spacebook">
        <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://animeindo.video/category/gundam-build-fighter/" data-width="450" data-layout="box_count" data-show-faces="false" data-send="false"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can scrape data inside `class="cat_box_desc"`, but i will get all the data inside, i don't want it, i want to separate the data.

I don't know to separate the data like above screenshot there are **status**, **genre**, **description**, **information** and others in the **H1** and **P** tag, because there are no **class** or **id** specified on it.

So how to do it in Beautifulsoup4..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already made a very good choice to go with BeautifulSoup as it is very flexible library with lots of ways of locating elements.

For the `:`-separated fields, I'd parse them out to a dictionary for easier access:

```
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<div class="cat_box_desc">
    <h3>Status:</h3>
    on-going <br>
    <h3>Genres:</h3>

    <br>
    <h3>Description:</h3>
    <div align="justify">
        <p> Information</p>
        <p>Type: TV</p>
        <p>Episodes: Unknown</p>
        <p>Status: Currently Airing</p>
        <p>Aired: Oct 7, 2013 to ?</p>
        <p>Producers: Sunrise, TV Tokyo, Sotsu Agency</p>
        <p>Genres: Mecha</p>
        <p>Duration: 25 min. per episode</p>
        <p>Synopsis:</p>
        <p>Gundam Build Fighter adalah sebuah pertarungan simulasi Gundam. Unit Gundam dirangkai dari model plastiknya. Tokoh utamanya adalah seorang anak laki-laki yang bernama Iori Sei. Sei memiliki kemampuan merangkai Gundam yang hebat, namun dia tak
            memiliki kemampuan untuk mengendalikan gundam yang ia rangkai saat melakukan Gunpla Battle. Namun satu hari dia bertemu dengan seorang pencuri roti misterius, yang memberinya sebuah batu permata.</p>
    </div><br>
    <div style="padding-left: 560px; padding-bottom:20px;" class="spacebook">
        <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://animeindo.video/category/gundam-build-fighter/" data-width="450" data-layout="box_count" data-show-faces="false" data-send="false"></div>
    </div>
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

# first locate the container with the desired fields
description = soup.find("h3", text="Description:").find_next_sibling()

# get all the ":"-separated fields into a dictionary 
pattern = re.compile(r"\w+:\s.*?")

data = dict(field.split(":") for field in description.find_all(text=pattern))

print(data)
```

Print:

```
{'Type': ' TV', 'Episodes': ' Unknown', 'Status': ' Currently Airing', 'Aired': ' Oct 7, 2013 to ?', 'Producers': ' Sunrise, TV Tokyo, Sotsu Agency', 'Genres': ' Mecha', 'Duration': ' 25 min. per episode'}
```

Now this does not catch `Synopsis` as it's value is in a separate `p` element, but you could get it via:

```
data["Synopsis"] = description.find("p", text="Synopsis:").find_next_sibling("p").get_text()
```

Complete prettified output:

```
{'Aired': ' Oct 7, 2013 to ?',
 'Duration': ' 25 min. per episode',
 'Episodes': ' Unknown',
 'Genres': ' Mecha',
 'Producers': ' Sunrise, TV Tokyo, Sotsu Agency',
 'Status': ' Currently Airing',
 'Synopsis': 'Gundam Build Fighter adalah sebuah pertarungan simulasi Gundam. '
             'Unit Gundam dirangkai dari model plastiknya. Tokoh utamanya '
             'adalah seorang anak laki-laki yang bernama Iori Sei. Sei '
             'memiliki kemampuan merangkai Gundam yang hebat, namun dia tak\n'
             '            memiliki kemampuan untuk mengendalikan gundam yang '
             'ia rangkai saat melakukan Gunpla Battle. Namun satu hari dia '
             'bertemu dengan seorang pencuri roti misterius, yang memberinya '
             'sebuah batu permata.',
 'Type': ' TV'}
```

---

We've used a few techniques here, below are the documentation links to the appropriate section of the library documentation. Make sure to look it up to get a better feel for these features:

- [The string/text argument](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-string-argument)
- [Regular expression filter](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression)
- [Going sideways](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling)